# Memory leak in JavaScript for event handing

Tags: javascript

Does the following function has memory leak?

```
var d = document.getElementById("d");
d.onclick = function() {

    // blah...

};
```

Comment: You're creating the variable `d` but binding a `click` handler to the element `div`, is this your *actual* code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="parent">
<span id="child">I am a span</span>
</div>
```

this is okie

```
    var d = document.getElementById("child");
    d.onclick = function() {

    // blah...    
};
```

//clearing an event from dom before removing handler from it will result in memory loss

now doing this will start leaking memory

```
   document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML="";
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no memory leak here.

Additionally, you can use array de-referencing if you want to just do it in one line -

```
document.getElementById("d").onclick = function() {
    // blah...
};
```

but this is dangerous if the element isn't present (or the DOM's not ready, etc.), as `document.getElementById` returns `null` if the object isn't found in the DOM (and *though* `null` is an `object` when you `typeof`, it's not cool with you trying to set properties on it).

Ah, the quirks of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is not memory leak. It's attaching `onclick` handler to a DOM element and is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

No.

All local variables, that is variables declared inside a function(on stack) tends to lose the scope as soon as the method call is complete.

Also, when you are done with the `d` you can delete it as well; `delete d;`

Comment: Delete d; does not work. Delete is only for object properties. However, d = null; works.